# OneWay Anova Contrasts : "singular contrast matrix"

Tags: r, anova

I have a small problem with defining contrasts for a one way anova ; I have try a lot of methods , but can't seem to find the proper one.

I have this kind of design :

```
$ Categorie     : Factor w/ 15 levels "Culture","culture_loisirs",..: 9 2 12 12 2 3 12 13 9 13 ...
$ RT            : num  932 1142 1238 680 983 ...
```

In my One-Way Anova I want to do a priori contrasts as follow :

```
cbind(c1,c2,c3)
      c1 c2 c3
[1,] -1.0 -1 -1
[2,] -1.0 -1 -1
[3,] -1.0 -1 -1
[4,] -1.0 -1 -1
[5,] -1.0 -1 -1
[6,]  6.5 13  0
[7,] -1.0 -1 -1
[8,]  6.5  0 13
[9,] -1.0 -1 -1
[10,] -1.0 -1 -1
[11,] -1.0 -1 -1
[12,] -1.0 -1 -1
[13,] -1.0 -1 -1
[14,] -1.0 -1 -1
[15,] -1.0 -1 -1
```

But when I try do redefine the contrasts of data$Categorie , R returns :

```
contrasts(data$Categorie) <- cbind(c1,c2,c3)
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6.5, -1,                         
:singular contrast matrix
```

This problem doesn't appear if I use any 2 of this contrasts

```
contrasts(data$Categorie) <- cbind(c1,c2)
contrasts(data$Categorie) <- cbind(c1,c3)
etc.
```

Do you have any clue of why this is ?

Comment: What is the concept where you lack understanding? It's possible for a matrix to be singular even when there are no two-way combinations of columns that are linear combinations of each other.

Comment: Thanks ! But I don't understand why I can't use this matrix as a contrast matrix ? what do I have to change for it to works ? add one contrast for it not to be singular ?

Comment: Adding a contrast will not make it non-singular.  `2*Col1 == Col2+Col3`.